# three.js transparent texture and shader material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using a circle texture to render particles:

[image]

The circle has transparent pixels. I'm using `ShaderMaterial` and `BufferGeometry` to provide custom size, color for each node. However I'm stuck with proper z-index rendering. In the image below:

[image]

The white particle is the nearest to the camera, the cyan (`0x00ffff`) is the second, and hibiscus color on the top right (`0xC3206F` looks pinkish) is the farthest.

As you can see the order is not correct. Ideally white circle should fully override cyan, and partially cover hibiscus. If I set `depthTest: true` for `ShaderMaterial`, the transparent regions of the texture become solid:

[image]

Here is the full source code: http://jsbin.com/mikimifipi/edit?js,output

I'm probably missing something with blending or messed up with the shaders. Can you please help?

Comment: :) done! Your comment was helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The particles are rendered in the order specified by `BufferGeometry`.
2. If `depthTest = true`, the material is not becoming solid, as you claim -- the particles behind it (and rendered later) are simply not being rendered at all.
3. You can improve some artifacts by setting `if ( tColor.a < 0.5 ) discard;`.
4. You likely should not be premultiplying your fragment shader output RGB by alpha. That is not the correct thing to do when using the default alpha-blending in three.js. It is also is what is causing the ring to appear around the white disk.

three.js r.71

Comment: Thank you! They alpha test discard was exactly what I needed.